# Validate data in Radgrid before changing pages

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

I want to validate the users changes on a page before allowing them to go to another page.  If the validation fails I want to stop the pager from changing the page.

For example:

```
protected void rgOrderItem_PageIndexChanged(object source, GridPageChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Mapvalues(false))
    {
        rgOrderItem.CurrentPageIndex = LastPageIndex;
        rgOrderItem.DataBind();
    }
}
```

This does not work.  The pager changes regardless.  Anyone know how to stop a page change event?
Thanks, Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
protected void RadGrid1_PageSizeChanged(object sender, GridPageSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Mapvalues(false))
    {
        e.Canceled = true; //Prevent to execute pagging functionality
    }
}
protected void RadGrid1_PageIndexChanged(object sender, GridPageChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Mapvalues(false))
    {
        e.Canceled = true; //Prevent to execute pagging functionality
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This works great.  I could not find the answer by searching because too many unrelated topics returned from my keywords.  Glad it was this simple.